# Agregar margen en multicell en fpdf

Tags: fpdf

Estoy intentando hacer un reporte con la librería FPDF, lo que busco es que exista un margen entre donde empieza la fila de multicell y donde imprime el texto como lo muestra la imagen,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero , no logro hacer que quede. Este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado tablas pero estas no me funcionan ya que los valores que toma X y Y son estáticos, entonces no me funciona porque cada reporte es diferente ya que puede tener todos los campos o no y eso hace que la posición X y Y sea dinámica.

Agradecería algún tipo de ayuda y/o orientación que me puedan proporcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te puedo sugerir una funcion que ya te ofrece FPDF y es margin

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10,50,0);
```

Con esto haces que la tabla en vez de que se siga y siga y comience de nuevo pero de modo de que iniciando una pagina nueva no se posisicione de modo irregular, si no que se posisicione de manera que aun sea presentable el trabajo.

Checalo y dime si te funciona!

Saludos!